# Kendo DropDownList Conditional if else template

Tags: javascript, templates, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, conditional-statements

Currently my template looks like this:

```
template: '#:data.Name# (#:data.Code#)'
```

What I would like to do is to check the data.Code parameter if it's empty.
If (data.Code == '') then

```
template: '#:data.Name#
```

else the first template that contains both name and code.

I've been trying something like this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
template: "#if(#:data.Code#==''){ #:data.Name# (#:data.Code#)}else {#:data.Name#}#"
```

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. You can find the removed solution in your [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44943379/revisions). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
tempalte: "#: Name # # if (data.Code) { # (#= Code #) # } #"
```

If I break it down it will be more clear:

```
#: Name #
# if (data.Code) { #
    (#: Code #)
# } #
```

As you see, the rules are as follows:

1. JS code should be placed between two `#`.
2. Values should be placed between a `#:` and a `#`.

Comment: Thank you. Managed to resolve the issue (See the edit).

Comment: Your solution is more complex than what is necessary. See my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`template: "#=data.Name# # if(data.Code != '') { # (#=data.Code#) # } #"`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work with help from replys.

```
template: "# if(data.Code != '')" +
          "{# #:data.Name# (#:data.Code#) #}" +
          "else {# #:data.Name# #} #"
```

Comment: You can't just post an answer yourself after getting it from other users :/

Comment: What I got from users is syntax, the knowledge of placing '#' on the right spots, not the exact answer to my question with the right semmantics, so why not?

Comment: Punit's answer and mine both are the exact code you need to use, not just a hint to a solution. As I stated in the comment to my answer, both of our solutions are better than yours since you do extra work by evaluating `#:data.Name#` twice.

Comment: No they are not, I've tried them, they do not work as expected, they're partly solutions on top of which I had to use extra logic. So tell me again. How does your code produce output like [this](https://i.imgur.com/hU9t0qC.png)?

Comment: It writes `Name` and then only if there is `Code`, it writes `(Code)` afterwards.